# how to have different dates on datepicker and on the input box?

Tags: reactjs, input, datepicker

I'm using react and [react datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/) and I want to be able to have a initial date on datepicker different from the initial date on input box, [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/557u1.png). I need them to be different only when they are initial dates, if the user selects a new date, then the date on the datepicker and the date on the input box should be the same as usual. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom input](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-43) of datepicker should solve your task.

Here is the copy of sample code from documentation

```
class ExampleCustomInput extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <button
                className="example-custom-input"
                onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {this.props.value}  // THis value will be displayed in input control
            </button>
        )
    }
}

ExampleCustomInput.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func,
    value: PropTypes.string
};

...

<DatePicker
     customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
     selected={this.state.startDate}   // This value will be selected when datepicker control shows up
     onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Just replace `<Button/>` control with `<Input/>` and style it accordinally. Also manage `this.props.value` and `this.state.startDate` from single callback to make them the same after user selects date in datepicker